# How to vertically align text in different examples using gb4e?

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, gb4e

I'm trying to reproduce the following exemples using gb4e:

[image]

Usually I would only vertically align the text within the same exemple, for glossing, for instance. But in this case, i have to align the text of one example with the text of another exemple.

How can I do this usign gb4e or any other package?

Comment: please show us what you try so far. the best in the form of small but complete document.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432506/35864 where the OP presents their solution using `tabbing` and another solution with `tabular` is given in the answers.